# Regular expression: extract css class out of string with multiple classes

Tags: css, regex

I've got a string that I have to match and extract a css class name out of it. The string:

```
.c.-my-text-overlay-second
```

the class I have to match has to contain `text-overlay` inside or at the end of the class name.
So in this case, what I want to extract is `.-my-text-overlay-second`.

I have tried multiple things, but I either get the `.c`:

```
(.*\..*?text-overlay.*)
```

or I get only `text-overlay`:

```
.*(\..*?media-overlay-active)
```

What should be the correct expression?

Comment: Maybe you are tying to do it this way [`\.[\w-]*text-overlay[\w-]*`](https://regex101.com/r/O46hA0/2)

Comment: @revo this is correct. Great regex work! The link is useful, I will be able to understand how the hell it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use a greedy dot `.*` in your Regular Expression since it will match everything from beginning to the point the next pattern (if exists) matches. That's the reason of matching whole input string while `text-overlay` exists in it.

Your regex should begin with a dot and the rest should correspond to class naming rules:

```
\.[\w-]*text-overlay[\w-]*
```